# Why my z-index dont working correctly on my divs?

Tags: html, sass, position, z-index

I would like to ask, why my z-index don´t working? I building a website with section with top teachers. There are 3 cards and I want to set medails on this cards. I would like to have .medal behind .card. But it is before. I tried changing z-index, positions and use !important.

HTML

```
    <div id="champions-container">
      <div class="champions-heading">
        <img src="css/img/logo.png" alt="" srcset=""><h2>Top teachers</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card card-1">
          <img src="css/img/avatar.png" alt="" srcset="">
          <a href="#"><h3>Name Surname</h3></a>
          <p>Čj, Aj, M, Ch</p>
          <div class="row">
            <img src="css/img/emoji.svg" alt="" srcset="">
            <span>300 CZK / h</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="p-btn">Send message</a>
          <div class="medal">
            <img src="css/img/silver.png" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-2">
          <img src="css/img/avatar.png" alt="" srcset="">
          <a href="#"><h3>Name Surname</h3></a>
          <p>Čj, Aj, M, Ch</p>
          <div class="row">
            <img src="css/img/emoji.svg" alt="" srcset="">
            <span>300 CZK / h</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="p-btn">Send message</a>
          <div class="medal">
            <img src="css/img/gold.png" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="css/img/avatar.png" alt="" srcset="">
          <a href="#"><h3>Name Surname</h3></a>
          <p>Čj, Aj, M, Ch</p>
          <div class="row">
            <img src="css/img/emoji.svg" alt="" srcset="">
            <span>300 CZK / h</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="p-btn">Send message</a>
          <div class="medal">
            <img src="css/img/bronze.png" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
#champions-container{
    padding: 8rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    .champions-heading{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-bottom: 6rem;
        h2{
            font-size: 4rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        img{
            width: 5rem;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
    }
    .card-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .card {
        width: 40rem;
        padding: 4rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: $white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 1.5rem;
        z-index: 1;
        img{
            width: 32rem;
            height: 32rem;
            object-fit: cover;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        h3{
            font-size: 2.8rem;
            margin: 0.5rem 0rem;
            margin-top: 1.5rem;
        }
        p{
            margin: 0.5rem 0rem;
            font-size: 2.2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .row{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 0.5rem 0rem;
            img{
                width: 5rem;
                height: 5rem;
            }
            span{
                font-size: 2.2rem;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
        .p-btn{
            text-align: center;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0.5rem auto;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .medal{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -23rem;
            transform: translateX(-4rem);
            z-index: -1 !important;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            img{
                width: 20rem;
                object-fit: contain;
            }
          }
      }
      
      .card-1 {
        z-index: 1;
        transform: scale(0.85);
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        transition: ease 0.3s all;
        &:hover{
            transform: scale(0.90);
        }
      }
      
      .card-2 {
        z-index: 2;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        transition: ease 0.3s all;
        &:hover{
            transform: scale(1.05);
        }
      }
      
      .card-3 {
        z-index: 1;
        transform: scale(0.85);
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        transition: ease 0.3s all;
        &:hover{
            transform: scale(0.90);
        }
      }   
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: That's not CSS. That's LESS or SASS or another CSS preprocessor. Please either update your question's tags or post the actual CSS.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, its SASS. Ok I will update my question tag.

Comment: You could remove all `z-index` from the `.cards` and remove the `transform` from the cards.